# SpringMVC how to Bind A Multi Select Option Element

Tags: java, spring-mvc, data-binding, binding, databinder

I have four select option list two are populated with data form the database and two are multi selects which are bind to the POJO. I then use java script to add options form the database select option list into the bind select option list however when i submit to the controller if the form is returned with errors and the select option list have data in it the data is lost.

The list items are both getting data properly only when the form is posted to the controller if the validation finds any errors and returns the form if these fields had data its lost.

I may have to write a CustomCollectionEditor for the list items in the class how can this be done?

**Crime.java**

```
public class Crime {

    private int crimeRecNo;
    private String crimeDetails;
    private double crimeLatLocation;
    private double crimeLongLocation;
    private String crimeStreetLn1;
    private String crimeStreetLn2;
    private Date crimeDate;
    private String crimeTime;
    private List<Citizens> victims;
    private List<Citizens> criminals;   
    private String recordedById;

//setters and getters
```

**jsp:**

```
<ol>
<li><label>Victims List</label><button id="addVictimBtn">+/button>

<form:select path="" id="dbvictims" title="Victims Of Crime" class="victimLst">
<form:options items="${dbvictims.dbvictimList}" itemValue="socialSecurityNumber" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select>                      

<label>Victims In Crime</label><button id="removeVictimBtn">-</button> 
<form:select path="victims" id="victims" title="Victims Of Crime"  multiple="multiple" class="victimLst">
<form:options items="${victims.victimList}" itemValue="socialSecurityNumber" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select><form:errors path="victims" class="errors" />                            
</li>
</ol>                           

<ol>
<li>
<label>Criminals List</label><button id="addCriminalBtn">+</button>
<form:select path="" id="dbcriminals" title="Criminals Of Crime" class="criminalsLst">
<form:options items="${dbcriminals.dbcriminalList}" itemValue="socialSecurityNumber" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select>  

<label>Criminals In Crime</label><button id="removeCriminalBtn">-</button> 
<form:select path="criminals" id="criminals" title="Criminals Of Crime"  multiple="multiple" class="criminalsLst">
<form:options items="${criminals.criminalList}" itemValue="socialSecurityNumber" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select><form:errors path="criminals" class="errors" />                           
</li>
</ol>
```

**Jquery**
This is used to add items from the dblist to the from bind list elements

```
    $('#addVictimBtn').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var victimId = $('#dbvictims option:selected').val();
        var victimName = $('#dbvictims option:selected').text();
        var options = '<option value="'+ victimId +'">' + victimName +'</option>';
        var exists = false;

    $('#victims option').each(function(){
        //alert($(this).val());
        if(this.value == victimId){

            exists = true;
        }                               
    });         

    if(!exists){
        $('#victims').append(options);              
    }           
    return false;           
});


$('#addCriminalBtn').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var criminalId = $('#dbcriminals option:selected').val();
    var criminalName = $('#dbcriminals option:selected').text();
    var options = '<option value="'+ criminalId +'">' + criminalName +'</option>';
    var exists = false;

    $('#criminals option').each(function(){
        //alert($(this).val());
        if(this.value == criminalId){

            exists = true;
        }                               
    });         

    if(!exists){
        $('#criminals').append(options);            
    }           
    return false;           
});
```

**Validation**

```
try{
   if(crime.getCriminals().isEmpty()){
    errors.rejectValue("criminals", "criminals.required");
   }                    

}catch(Exception e){
     errors.rejectValue("criminals", "criminals.required");
}


try{
   if(crime.getVictims().isEmpty()){
    errors.rejectValue("victims", "victims.required");
   }
}catch(Exception e){
    errors.rejectValue("victims", "victims.required");
}
```

**Error**

In the multi list if i select the options and then post the form i am getting the following error message

**Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String[] to required type java.util.List for property victims; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.crimetrack.business.Citizens] for property victims[0]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
Invalid List Of Victims**

**Log**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.crimetrack.business.Citizens.<init>(java.lang.String)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedCollection(TypeConverterDelegate.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:179)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:470)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:692)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
99160 [http-bio-8084-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate  - Field [198501011] isn't an enum value
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: 198501011
    at java.lang.Class.getField(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.attemptToConvertStringToEnum(TypeConverterDelegate.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedCollection(TypeConverterDelegate.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:179)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:470)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:692)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
99160 [http-bio-8084-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate  - Converting String to [class java.lang.String] using property editor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor@339a86e6]
99160 [http-bio-8084-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate  - Converting String to [int] using property editor [com.crimetrack.service.CustomIntEditor@74a3d72e]
99160 [http-bio-8084-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate  - Converting String to [int] using property editor [com.crimetrack.service.CustomIntEditor@74a3d72e]
99160 [http-bio-8084-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate  - No String constructor found on type [com.crimetrack.business.Citizens]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.crimetrack.business.Citizens.<init>(java.lang.String)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedCollection(TypeConverterDelegate.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:179)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:470)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:692)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
99160 [http-bio-8084-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate  - Field [194302025] isn't an enum value
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: 194302025
    at java.lang.Class.getField(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.attemptToConvertStringToEnum(TypeConverterDelegate.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedCollection(TypeConverterDelegate.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:179)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:470)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:692)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
99160 [http-bio-8084-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod  - Invoking [handleSave] method with arguments [com.crimetrack.business.Crime@32562ce3, org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 13 errors
Field error in object 'crime' on field 'criminals': rejected value [198501011,198501012]; codes [typeMismatch.crime.criminals,typeMismatch.criminals,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [crime.criminals,criminals]; arguments []; default message [criminals]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'criminals'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.crimetrack.business.Citizens] for property 'criminals[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
Field error in object 'crime' on field 'victims': rejected value [194302025,1985010122]; codes [typeMismatch.crime.victims,typeMismatch.victims,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [crime.victims,victims]; arguments []; default message [victims]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'victims'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.crimetrack.business.Citizens] for property 'victims[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

Comment: can anyone assists here?

Comment: You said that the data lost, you mean that you can't get data in controller or can't get it in the form?

Comment: I cannot get the data in the form when i post the validation is called and that also doesn't get the data because the validation returns errors on the multi list so the validation if list is empty is true.

Comment: The criminal and victim multi select option lists gets their data from the execution of a jquery function which adds the data from another list

Comment: you can see i included an error message above